How to create subscriptions with PayPal Advanced Checkout?
We currently use the SetExpressCheckout NVP endpoint to handle checkout flows for both one-time payments and to set up payment subscriptions.
As the NVP/SOAP APIs are legacy integration methods, we are considering moving to PayPal Advanced Checkout, but there isn't any sample code for setting up subscriptions with Advanced Checkout. Is setting up subscriptions with Advanced Checkout currently possible? If not, is this a planned feature?
Alternatively, is there a different PayPal payment flow that would be better suited for one-time payments, subscriptions, and SCA compliance?
I tried looking at the PayPal PHP Server SDK that was used in the sample code for PayPal Advanced Checkout, but it doesn't support the Subscriptions endpoint yet.

You'll need to use HTTPS REST API calls (in JSON format) for the Subscriptions endpoints. It's documented here, and ultimately provides the same functionality as the old SetExpressCheckout does for recurring payments.
For one-time payments, the Advanced checkout is only needed if you want to customize credit card fields. If the black "Debit or Credit Card" button's card fields work for you, you don't need to implement Advanced (just Standard)
